# Кнопка для добавления строк в QTableWidget в заголовке таблицы

Tags: python, pyqt5, header, qtablewidget

В MS Word, когда вы наводите курсор на границы таблицы, между строками, на которые направлен курсор, появляется знак "+" (прилагаю скриншот). Как добавить такую же кнопку в заголовок QTableWidget?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import sys


class Window_app:
    global app, tab
    app = QApplication([])
    tab = QTabWidget()
    tab.setGeometry(0, 0, QApplication.desktop().width(), QApplication.desktop().height())


class Get_from_residents:
    table = QTableWidget()
    headers = ['Table 1', 'Table 2', 'Table 3']
    table.setColumnCount(len(headers))
    table.setRowCount(8)
    table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(headers)


class Distributing_the_widgets_for_the_next_upload_of_your_bookmarks:
    grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
    grid.setColumnStretch (0, 10)
    grid.setRowStretch (10, 0)
    tab.setLayout(grid)

    grid.addWidget(Get_from_residents.table, 1, 0)
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tab.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Я задал этот вопрос ChatGPT, но написанный им код не решил мою проблему:

header = self.table.horizontalHeader()

```
header.sectionEntered.connect(
       lambda index:
           header.setIndexWidget(index,QPushButton("Button")))

header.sectionExited.connect(
      lambda index:
            header.setIndexWidget(index,None))

    self.setCentralWidget(self.table)
```